# Not able Running/deploying custom script with shub-image

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapinghub

I have problem for **Running/deploying** custom script with **shub-image**.

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = 'EU-Crawler',
    version = '1.0',
    packages = find_packages(),
    scripts = [
        'bin/launcher.py',
        'bin/DE_WEB_launcher.py',
        'bin/ES_WEB_launcher.py',
        'bin/FR_WEB_launcher.py',
        'bin/IT_WEB_launcher.py',
        'bin/NL_WEB_launcher.py',
        'bin/DE_MOBILE_launcher.py',
        'bin/FR_MOBILE_launcher.py'
    ],
    package_data = {
        'Crawling': ['*.ini'],
    },
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = Crawling.settings']},
    install_requires=[
        'scrapy-crawlera>=1.2.2',
        'configobj',
        'scrapy-fake-useragent',
        'xmltodict',
        'selenium==2.53.2',
        'python-dateutil',
        'pyvirtualdisplay',
        'beautifulsoup4',
        'incapsula-cracker-py3'
    ], 
    extras_require={'ScrapyElasticSearch': 'ScrapyElasticSearch[extras]'},
    zip_safe = False,
    include_package_data=True
)
```

in this file I have

```
scripts = [
       'bin/launcher.py',
       'bin/DE_WEB_launcher.py',
       'bin/ES_WEB_launcher.py',
       'bin/FR_WEB_launcher.py',
       'bin/IT_WEB_launcher.py',
       'bin/NL_WEB_launcher.py',
       'bin/DE_MOBILE_launcher.py',
       'bin/FR_MOBILE_launcher.py'
   ],
```

who are my differents filse that I want sent

I deploy with this command

```
sudo shub image upload --username [USERNAME] --password [PASSWORD]
```

Before I used **shub-image** version  0.2.5 et  **shub**  version 2.5.1 and I it worked well.

But now I use **shub** version **2.7.0** (shub image is now part of shub **2.70+** ) and I'm not able to deploy my scripts.

I got **no Error**, I transfer my **spiders** well, but **not** the **files in bin folder** .

**any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated**

Comment: What's your error? have you verified if your `scrapinghub.yml` contain `image: true`?

Comment: @Wilfredo yes i have image: true, and for the error i updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer my own question.

I switched to the version below for solving the problem, now I use version 2.6.1 and I have no problem.

I still have the problem with the version 2.7 but I think that this answer will help someone.